# Codeigniter distinct query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database query to select the distinct category. However, I have 2 joined tables, my distinct query is not working since it returns repeated categories. What code adjustment do I have to make? Here is my query code.

```
 $query = $this->db->distinct()
                    ->select('tbl_par.*, tbl_category.category_name')
                    ->or_like($array_like_param)
                    ->from($this->table_par)
                    ->join($this->table_cat,$this->table_cat.'.ID ='.$this->table_par.'.category')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('tbl_par.*, distinct tbl_category.category_name');
$this->db->or_like($array_like_param)
$this->db->from($this->table_par)
$this->db->join($this->table_cat,$this->table_cat.'.ID ='.$this->table_par.'.category')
$query=$this->db->get();
```